# Axhspan always in front of the figure

Tags: matplotlib, background

I'm trying to make a plot with scattered points.
I want to show specific area in the (xy) plan.
I've seen how to use axhspan ans axvspan but the coloured area it produces always hide my points.
I mean, I can see my points setting alpha to a value different from one but their colour is altered by the axhspan colour.

Is there any way to put such area in the background of the figure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to tell for sure without knowing exactly what you're doing (It's always a good idea to post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!), but it's likely that you want to use zorder to bring whatever you're plotting to the top. Higher zorder is towards the front (http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html).

So, for example, if you had a scatterplot that you wanted to show up in front, you would add the zorder argument, like this:

```
plt.scatter(X, Y, zorder = 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `zorder` keyword. Make the `zorder` of the thing you want on top higher than that which you want in the background.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.random.rand(100)
y=np.random.rand(100)

fig,(ax1,ax2)=plt.subplots(1,2)

# zorder of the points is higher, they will be on top of the axhspan
ax1.axhspan(0.25, 0.75, facecolor='r',zorder=1)
ax1.plot(x,y,'ko',zorder=2)

# zorder of the axhspan is higher, so it will be on top of the points
ax2.axhspan(0.25, 0.75, facecolor='b',zorder=2)
ax2.plot(x,y,'ko',zorder=1)

fig.savefig('zorder.png')
```

[image]